# What is this lettuce feeling oval shaped plant that grows similar to a rhubarb bush?

Tags: identification

physical description:
not hairy
grows in a ring (think rhubarb)
oval shaped
not oily
USDA 4A
Found thought the grass in the yard

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell from the photo, but my best guess would be broad-leaf plantain: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plantago_major. Does this look right to you? If not, a few closeup photos of the leaves (including the front) and the whole plant if possible would help.

Comment: And where you found the plant is also useful (continent, region and environment).

Comment: @michelle Looks like it, can I eat it?

Comment: Hey @Michelle, I agree with you. I think the description and even the unclear photos pretty much all point to Plantago. Go for an answer. :)

Comment: @blackthumb Go for it. Young leaves are good as salad, older ones are too hard and stringy, but prepping them like spinach works.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi basically correct, but plantago major is actually found almost world-wide...

Comment: I agree it's broad leaf plantain. But we really need a pic of the whole plant. We need to see how the leaves are arranged, what any flowers look like, etc.

Comment: Just mowed it, I need to give it a few days to come back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the plant you have is Plantago Major, commonly known as Broad-leaf plantain. It's commonly found anywhere there is poor or disturbed soil, including as a lawn weed.

You asked whether it is edible. The answer is apparently yes, although I've never tried it myself and couldn't tell you whether it is worth eating. I can tell you that as the leaf matures, it develops strings not unlike those in celery, but much, much tougher. I think you'd probably want to stick to very early leaves if you were to eat it.